# Foreach: Razor with Javascript method inside tbody

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor

all. 
I'm trying to create a table dynamically. So inside the tbody tag I have this code which may generate all the rows.

```
       <tbody id="body">
            @foreach (FoodkitGestores.Entidades.MenuCantidad m in Model.p.listaMenu)
            {

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var idMenu = Number(@m.idMenu);
                    var nombre = $("#menu-"+idMenu).find(".item").text();
                    var precio = parseFloat($("#menu-"+idMenu).find(".item").attr("data-precio"));
                    var cantidad = Number(@m.cantidad);
                    var cantidadEntregada = Number(@m.cantidadEntregada);    

                    AgregarMenu(idMenu, nombre, precio, cantidad, cantidadEntregada);            
                </script>

            }
        </tbody>
```

So, the thing is that it's not finding the function "AgregarMenu". Says that it is not defined. But it is and I tested it, and it's working.

I tried by adding  tag but it isn't supported by HTML5 inside tbody, and also it's not working. It just write literally "AgregarMenu(idMenu, nombre, precio, cantidad, cantidadEntregada);"

Any clue?
Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
AgregarMenu is a Javascript method that is inside a .js file already referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `AgregarMenu` is a javascript method, You need to make sure that the script where you defined the method is loaded **BEFORE** the part where you call the method.

If you have this function defined in an external javascript file, make sure you include that **ABOVE** your foreach code.May be in the top of your view.

Even though this may fix your current problem, I recommend you to do some kind of templating logic instead of calling the AggregarMenu mehtod many times inside the loop. Tim's answer is a good option or you may look into some other templating solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it would be better to decorate the items with data attributes and build a single script that would iterate over the items, pull the values from the data attributes, and  apply the function. As it is, you've got repeating definitions of variables littering your global namespace by repeating the same code with different values outside of a function definition.  If you do this and make sure that the method is run after DOM load, as long as the function is on the page it should both work and be a cleaner implementation.

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach (FoodkitGestores.Entidades.MenuCantidad m in Model.p.listaMenu)
{
  <tr id="menu-@m.idMenu" 
      class="menu" 
      data-id="@m.idMenu"
      data-cantidad="@m.cantidad" 
      data-cantidadEntregada="@m.cantidadEntregada">
        <td class="item" data-precio="35.15">35.15</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.menu').each(function() {
           var $this = $(this),
               nombre = Number($this.data('id')),
               parseFloat($this.find(".item").data("precio")),
               cantidad = Number($this.data('cantidad'));
               cantidadEntregada = Number($this.data('cantidadEntregada');    
           AgregarMenu(idMenu, nombre, precio, cantidad, cantidadEntregada);
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Suggest accepted! Thanks a lot, i'll implement this